# How to get the event when prev,next are clicked : Schedule with primefaces

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar

I have added PrimeFaces schedule from [this page](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule/basic.xhtml) and got the results like the following:

[image]

I got the following events working fine but how do I get and handle events when `prev` or `next` is clicked?

I have also highlighted some more in the image:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleJava8View.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
            <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleJava8View.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
            <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleJava8View.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
            <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleJava8View.onEventResize}" update="messages" />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211063/discussion-on-question-by-codenotfound-how-to-get-the-event-when-prev-next-are-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture dates / view changes on the server / in your bean, I found it easiest to just go for lazy loading ([showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule/lazy.xhtml), [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/schedule?id=lazy-loading)). This will basically allow you to have a method in the bean where the start and end date are passed in case the view changes:

```java
lazyModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {
  @Override
  public void loadEvents(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
    //
  }
};
```

.. and as a bonus, your events will be lazily loaded!

Note that the type of dates (`java.time.LocalDateTime` or `java.util.Date`) will depend on the PrimeFaces version. See the [migration guide](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide).

To modify the UI, you need to know that PrimeFaces is using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) for the `p:schedule` component. You can use the [`extender`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/schedule?id=extender-method) attribute and configure the FullCalendar to your needs. See the [toolbar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/toolbar). Note that the version of FullCalendar will depend on the PrimeFaces version. Again, see the migration guide.

To set the time format, use the `timeFormat` attribute. It uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/). You could use `hh:mmA`. Try it on https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule/configureable.xhtml