# How to change button label and time format in p:schedule

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar

I have used [schedule](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule/basic.xhtml) from PrimeFaces. How can I change the time format and button label?

Comment: @JasperdeVries, Yes, Thank you very much and i tried this today and it worked the way i wanted. upvoted your answer already and will mark it as accepted now.

Comment: @JasperdeVries, If you dont mind and if you could spend time then could you please help me as how to enable and disable prev and next programmatically? and is it possible to place a text between prev and next which is from managed bean?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat and some CSS?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Sure, will try this and how to enable and disable prev and next programmatically?

Comment: @JasperdeVries i think No.

Comment: Please create a new question for that

Comment: @JasperdeVries, Sure, Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074931/how-to-enable-or-disable-prev-next-programmatically-schedule-with-primefaces

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other question. The other question contained two questions in one. That should be split (and sort of was, clearly the title) The main part of answer on the 'duplicate' is about the events and just hints at a solution for the labels. This is explicitly about the button labels and the other about the events. So I voted to reopen this.

Comment: @Kukeltje, You are welcome, i have also added the valid code that i am using, i just need some way to hide and show only the selected radio and others should be un selected(basically one radion ONLY can be selected), Please share some hints if you dont mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Primefaces used jquery FullCalendar like mentioned by @JasperDeVries in the answer in [How to get the event when prev,next are clicked in p:schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004498/how-to-get-the-event-when-prev-next-are-clicked-in-pschedule?noredirect=1#comment108018510_61004498) and PrimeFaces has extender functionality (also referred to in the same answer to a different issue) I was able to fix the time format issue with `timeFormat="LT"` also used  `extender="initSchedule"` to change the button label.

```
 <h:outputScript>
            function initSchedule() {
                // Configure fullCalendar
                this.cfg.eventOrder = "-title"; // Sort descending order
                this.cfg.buttonText = { today : 'Current Date'};
                    }
    </h:outputScript>
```